# Vertex Group With Checker Deselect

Tags: mesh

I' trying to create a vertex group with checker deselect,
[image: Checker deselect Selection]
and trying to create a vertex group with that selection, but when a select the vertices of that vertex group it selects the entire cube and the selection that I made before gets replaces.

Any suggestion to trying to solve this?

PS:. I'm new to blender so if am going something wrong I would appreciate that someone would point it out to me.

Thank you.

Comment: It's impossible to save that selection into vertex group. You can try saving into material slot (a hack basically), extruding selected on your screenshot and saving that to group or detaching selected vertices with Y and using 2 meshes (a hack). It all depends on what is your goal with that vertex group

Comment: "It's impossible".... because it's a selection of _all_ the vertices, and a vertex group contains no information about how the vertices are used in faces. What you need is a way of storing a selection of faces.. as demo'd by Mr Zak.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will try using a material slot instead, but I want the vertices to be connected, because I will try to render something using a texture like glass and if I don't use a single mesh it will take to long to render and the refraction, I think it will make it look awful. Here it is what im trying to do: http://brokenliquid.com, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the image, you have selected every other face and now have half of the faces selected. Vertex groups can only contain vertices, so for each face, blender is selecting the vertices that make up the four corners of each square. Because your selection of faces touches all the vertices in the cube, Blender adds all the vertices in the cube to the vertex group.

To see exactly what this is doing, try selecting just one face, then switch to vertex select mode to see what vertices selects.

To get every other **vertex** selected, you can go into vertex select mode and select every other vertex before grouping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning blender and came across this same question i had.

FYI, I'm using Blender 3.1 currently.

After configuring the checker deselect use one of the options below

Option 1. **Vertext** -> **Vertex Groups** -> **Assign to New Group**

Option 2. You can also use the hotkey **Ctrl+G**

Look in your vertex groups now and you will have a new group.

Use the **select** and **deselect** buttons to confirm